Improving my GPA after two disastrous years
I am a computer science student and  had disastrous first two years.There are many F's on my transcript and my overall GPA was 2.44/4.00.Then I retook all the courses that I had failed and improved my GPA to 3.34/4.00.I have another year before graduation and will keep improving but I am worried about the F's and D's on my transcript even if I retook the courses and passed with A's.Will they be problem in Msc and PhD applications? There is no special reason for that poor performance.I just didn't plan a career in academia but then I changed my opinion and decided to make a come-back.Is this a valid excuse?
In my country,only the most recent grade is counted in GPA calculation but all grades for the specific course appear on transcript.

I don't understand what answer you are looking for. If admissions are competitive, you will be competing against people that did not have any disasterous years of grades.

Don’t look for excuses - they’re just signs you did something wrong. If your GPA is sufficient then that’s it, and if they will look at the details you can’t change that either. No advice from us will allow you to change the past.

In most schools and most departments, admission to grad school is highly competitive. "A lot of Fs" is definitely going to be a problem. Maybe that's not the answer you want, but it's the only answer there is, especially since there is no real reason for those Fs.

Your most recent new courses -- have you passed those, the first time, with A's?

Yes, very poor grades will be a concern for some applications. However, many (most?) people recognize that young people "grow up" and change attitude and direction. This is part of the reason that only the latest grade is counted in GPA. In the US, perhaps especially, people, while still having concerns, will look at the latest grade as most important for indicating your current status.
Also, in the US, letters of recommendation can attest to the fact that, academically, you are a different person than you were at the start.
Yes, a concern, more serious some places than others, but not necessarily a block going forward as long as you continue good performance.

I can't speak for German institutions, but in the US, starting from scratch won't help as all prior records need to be submitted. You are where you are. Make the best of it and cast a wide net for future study. And continue to outperform your earlier self and not just in retaking courses but in new ones.

Sorry, but I won't be part of any committee or system that considers you. And the grades in the field you want to enter are most important. Get letters that mention your transformation if possible.
